# How to Read from and Post to a Remote Server using Java

Tags: java

I am new to this type of problems. Here I want to make a request to a website API and get response in JSON format.

I then want to send this response directly to a a different remote URL.

Answer (score 2):

See the below sample code

```
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("Your URL");

    post.setRequestBody("your json data");
    post.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

    // Get HTTP client
    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
    // Execute request
    try
    {
        int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);

        s_log.info("Response status code: " + result);
        s_log.info(post.getResponseBodyAsString());

    }
    catch (HttpException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {

        post.releaseConnection();
    }
```

Comment: You answer may be improved somewhat by mentioning the libraries you have utilized to implement the solution.

Comment: use this jar commons.httpclient.jar

Answer (score 2):

Reading from and writing to a remote URL can be done using the standard Java API and is detailed in the official Java tutorials:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Reading:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Writing

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage:  java Reverse "
                + "http://<location of your servlet/script>"
                + " string_to_reverse");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String stringToReverse = URLEncoder.encode(args[1], "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(args[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                         connection.getOutputStream());
        out.write("string=" + stringToReverse);
        out.close();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(
                                    connection.getInputStream()));
        String decodedString;
        while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(decodedString);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```